# Node.js performance bottleneck

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently working on a Node.js app which implement with Express.js. The bussiness is quite simple, send static JSON data alone with response. But when I test performance with ApacheBench the QPS is very poor, only about 1000q/s, this machine is 24 cores/96Gb, during the test CPU usage is around 3~5%, network I/O is also very low. Where could the bottleneck is?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have some source code? where comes the json data?

Comment: maybe you could try and send the JSON in multiple parts, let say 3, at once and join them up on the server side

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to judge without seeing code sample... Node.js is single thread so it won't "scale automatically" when you will increase number of cores. You can try spawn multiple processes with [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). However if your resource is static you should consider serving it with [Express static middleware](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) or consider e.g. nginx for such purposes.

Comment: did you meant nginx for static content only ? or can we also use ngnix for non-static api calls as well ? our api endpoint is making connection with S3 as well as DB, so there is a n/w dependency also. It works only till ~70 requests/sec then it crashes. Any help appreciated.